# Mysql count of a subquery column with having

Tags: mysql, count, subquery

I have a table called giveaways and each giveaway can have contestants. I am trying to get the number of giveaways without winners. The contestants table has a field called winner that is 1 or 0.

My data looks like:

Giveaway Table

```
| id | name       |
|----|------------|
| 1  | Giveaway 1 |
| 2  | Giveaway 2 |
```

Contestant Table

```
| id | giveaway_id|winner|
|----|------------|------|
| 1  | 1          | 0    |
| 2  | 1          | 0    |
| 3  | 2          | 0    |
```

This is my query :

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM contestants c 
        WHERE c.giveaway_id = g.id AND winner = 1) as winners
FROM giveaways g
having winners =  0
```

Right now this will return multiple rows, I want to get the count of rows. I tried wrapping a count() around the winners subquery but that did not work.

In the example above this would be returned:

```
Results
| winners |
|---------|
| 0       |
| 0       |
```

I want just the count of rows which would be 2.

What's a better approach? Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to get the number of giveaways without winners.

Use `NOT EXISTS` with a correlated subquery :

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    giveaways g
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM contestants WHERE giveaway_id = g.id AND winner = 1
)
```

The subquery ensures that there is no winning contestant for each giveaway to count.

Comment: Worked like a champ, I also found I could wrap my query with another subquery        

`SELECT count(*) as needs_winners FROM(SELECT (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM contestants c 
        WHERE c.giveaway_id = g.id AND winner = 1) as winners
FROM giveaways g
having winners =  0) as x`

but you have a much better approach! Thx